# soap based microservices development using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I am wondering is it possible to use spring boot to develop soap based microservices . if yes, could you share some useful links to achieve it.

Thank You.

Comment: Of course it is possible. Check out the official guides 
https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/
https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/

Comment: Just google `spring boot soap api` there are many resources regarding the matter.